# possible host addresses for an IPv4 address

Tags: network

How many possible host addresses are available for an IPv4 address where the first and second octets are reserved for network addresses?

Comment: is this combinatorics?

Comment: $2^8\times 2^8 = 2^{16}$ if you can only change the last two octets

Comment: SO: [What is the total amount of public IPv4 addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2437169)